# How to connect to REST API using JSON?

Tags: python, json, rest, api, python-requests

I am trying to connect to the CRUD of some service online with the REST API. But before I could use its API, I need to get a token from it. So, the algorithm is (as I understood):

1. **Form** the request with JSON in the body
2. **Get** the **token** from the web-service (In the form of JSON, I guess)

My question is, how can I make it in Python?

My code currently looks like this:

```
import requests
import discord


url = 'https://some-url-with-auth.com'
token = requests.post(url, data = {'email':'some@email.com', \
'api_key':'somepass'}, headers = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

print(token.json())
```

The `token.status_code()` gives me `200`. But I still get this error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kodiumbot.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(token.json())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 898, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this below, json() requires the token to be defined in a json form.
You have used single quotes and it cannot be parsed.

```
    url = "https://some-url-with-auth.com"
    token = requests.post(url, data={"email": "some@email.com", "api_key": "some pass"}, headers={"lAccept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"})

    print(token.json())
```